# ValueError related to Size of X Dataset Array in Jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-lab, valueerror, image-classification

I'm relatively new to tensorflow and I'm experiencing an error I don't know how to fix.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

X = X/255.0

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model = Sequential()

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model.add(Flatten()) 

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model.add(Dense(64))

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

x_val = X[-40:]
y_val = y[-40:]
X = X[:-40]
y = y[:-40]

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(tf.size(X))
print(tf.size(y))

model.fit(X, y, batch_size = 10, epochs = 10, validation_data = (x_val,y_val))
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-151ffb1a84e3> in <module>
     45               metrics=['accuracy'])
     46 
---> 47 model.fit(X, y, batch_size=10, epochs=10, validation_data = (x_val,y_val))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1048          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
   1049       # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch iteration.
-> 1050       data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
   1051           x=x,
   1052           y=y,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1098 
   1099     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
-> 1100     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1101         x,
   1102         y,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    272 
    273     num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(inputs)).pop()
--> 274     _check_data_cardinality(inputs)
    275 
    276     # If batch_size is not passed but steps is, calculate from the input data.

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1527           label, ", ".join(str(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(single_data)))
   1528     msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1529     raise ValueError(msg)
   1530 
   1531 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 2360
  y sizes: 760
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

It appears as if the x data at some point becomes 3 times the size as the y data, and this is the cause of the error. I believe both should be 800, but the x data appears to be 2400 currently. I tested by subtracting 1600 from the data at the same time as when I removed 40 from each for validation, and this fixed all of the errors, so it appears as if this is the cause of the issues. Does anyone know why the x data is 3 times the size of the y data?

Update: I have the code where the datasets are created here:

```
import random
import pickle

random.shuffle(training_data)

#for sample in training_data[:10]:
#    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []

for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

# print(X[0].reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1))

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y = np.array(y)

pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Update 2: It appears as if I have split the data correctly... does it have anything to do with how I'm using the jpeg files? Also, I tried using tf.size() to find the size of each array. It seems as if the y array behaves as expected, but the x array starts with a size of 13500000 and changes to 13275000 when i set aside 40 samples for validation.

Comment: You are trying to solve, binary classification problem. Please replace, categorical_crossentropy with binary_crossentropy.

Comment: @FelixTenn I tried that, and my first epoch worked, but I got the same error when it got to the second epoch.

Comment: Is this all for the stacktrace? This error log seems to be incomplete. If so, could you please include all of the lines? Also: your train/valid split seems wrong as the elements in each pair `(X, y)` and `(x_val, y_val)` should have the same size.

Comment: @Idavid I just updated that. Also, I had already changed the split when I got that error, but thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to update it in the post.

Comment: @FelixTenn also, upon running it again, the first epoch doesn’t work, that only happened once. Now, the error occurs at the same time as it originally had.

Comment: There should be something wrong with data shapes in the first place. The way you slice them seems correct and should not throw an error if they contain same number of samples.

Comment: @Frightera Does the code I added have anything that could've changed the size?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. The X values were 3 times as expected because 1 value was expected, but the images were in color, not grayscale, thus having 3 values instead of the expected 1.